# QuickSearch never be called

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, autocomplete

this is my code in .cshtml

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search","Home",
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "SearchResults",
        HttpMethod ="GET",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
    }
))
{
    <input type="text" id="q" data-autocomplete="@Url.Action("QuickSearch", "Home")"   />
    <input type="submit" value="Search"  />
}
<table id="SearchResults">
</table>
```

and in .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":input[data-autocomplete]").each(function () {
         $(this).autocomplete({ source: $(this).attr("data-autocomplete") });
    });
});
```

and in HomeController.cs  my QuickSearch is:

```
public ActionResult QuickSearch(string term)
{
    var _restaurant = context.Books.Where(r => r.BookTitle.Contains(term) )
                    .Take(10)
                    .Select(r => new
                    {
                        label = r.BookTitle
                    });
    return Json(_restaurant, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and I added `jquery-1.5.1.min.js`, `jquery-ui.css`, `jquery-ui.js`, `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js`, `modernizr-1.7.min.js`

My search button works very well but my autocomplete not working at all even not calling the method when i put breakpoint on QuickSearch method and debug it never invokes and executes the method.
BUT
for this

```
<a href="@Url.Action("QuickSearch", "Home")">url</a>
```

it works very well.

also in my other project everything works with no problem.

I really appreciate for any help.

Comment: after you've entered values in autocomplete box, you should take a look at browser console and see if you've got any errors in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem.
I had  a partial view in my page that had these at the top:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

so i deleted this script block from partial view and it works now.